Proof of Lemma 1 in Online Convex Optimization in the Bandit Setting: Gradient Descent without a Gradient
I was reading the paper Online Convex Optimization in the Bandit Setting: Gradient Descent without a Gradient and found some steps about the proof of Lemma 1 were missing.
In particular, the authors mention that the d-dimensional generalization, following from Stokes' theorem, is:
$$
\nabla\int_{\delta B}f(x+v)dv = \int_{\delta S}f(x+u)\frac{u}{||u||}du
$$
Also, they mention that by definition:
$$
E_{v \in B}[f(x + \delta v)]=\frac{\int_{\delta B}f(x+v)dv}{vol_d(\delta B)}
$$
But why?
Lemma 1: Fix $\delta \gt 0$, over random unit vectors $u$,
$$
\mathbb{E}_{u \in S}[f(x+\delta u)u] = \frac{\delta}{d}\nabla\hat{f}(x)
$$
Here $B$ and $S$ are the unit ball and sphere centered around the origin in $d$ dimensions, namely, $B =\{x\in R^d | |x| \le 1\}$, $S =\{x\in R^d | |x| = 1\}$.
Also, $\delta B$ and $\delta S$ are the ball and sphere of radius, respectively. $vol_{d}(B)$ and $vol_{d-1}(S)$ are ball volume of $B$ and sphere area of $S$, respectively.

Technically, this is a simple consequence of what is oftentimes called the generalised Stokes' theorem. The trouble here is that stating this usually requires the language of differential forms, which a lot of students in ML theory aren't too familiar with. It is, however, possible to give a direct proof. I don't know if this per se is helpful to see: the proof is long and you might be better off picking up the basics of differential forms instead :)

I'll assume that $f$ is continous everywhere. It suffices to argue this coordinate-wise, and wlog, only show the first component of the gradient satisfies the appropriate equality. We thus want to show that $$ \partial_{x_1} \int_{\delta B} f(x + v) \mathrm{d}v = \int_{\delta S} f(x+u) \frac{u_1}{\delta} \mathrm{d}\mathcal{S}_\delta( u),$$ where I use $\mathcal{S}_\delta$ to denote the standard measure on a sphere of radius $\delta$.
Now, fix some small $\varepsilon > 0,$ let $e_1$ denote the first unit vector in an orthonormal basis, and consider $$ g(\varepsilon):=  \int_{\delta B} f(x + \varepsilon e_1 + v) - f(x + v) \mathrm{d}v\\ = \int_{ B(\varepsilon e_1, \delta)} f(x+v) \mathrm{d}v - \int_{ B(0,\delta)} f(x+v) \mathrm{d}v,$$ where $B(z,r)$ denotes the ball of radius $r$ around $z$. Naturally, this reduces to $$ \int_{B(\varepsilon e_1, \delta) \setminus B(0,\delta)} f(x+v) \mathrm{d}v - \int_{B(0,\delta) \setminus B(\varepsilon e_1, \delta)} f(x+v)\mathrm{d}v =: A(\varepsilon) - B(\varepsilon).$$ I will analyse the behaviour of $A(\varepsilon)/\varepsilon$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$, and leave you to see that a parallel analysis works for $B(\varepsilon)$.
Now, consider the behaviour of the set $$ \Delta(\varepsilon, \delta) := B(\varepsilon e_1,\delta)\setminus B(0,\delta) = \{z : \|z_2^d\|^2 + (z_1 - \varepsilon )^2 \le \delta^2, \|z_2^d\|^2 + z_1^2 >\delta\}.$$ To relate things to the unit sphere, we will study this in polar coordinates: if $z = r\cdot u,$ where $u$ lies in the unit sphere and $r>0$, then $$z \in \Delta \iff r > \delta \textrm{ and } r^2  -2\varepsilon r u_1 + \varepsilon^2 \le \delta^2.$$ You can show with some cmoputation that solutions to the above exist only if $u_1 \ge \varepsilon/2\delta$ and that for a fixed $u,$ the range of $r$ is $$ \delta \le r \le \delta \sqrt{1 - \varepsilon^2 (1-u_1^2)/\delta^2} + \varepsilon u_1 =: \delta + \zeta(u,\varepsilon).$$
So, we can write  $$ A(\varepsilon) =  \int_{u: u_1 \ge \varepsilon/2\delta} \int_{r = \delta}^{r = \delta + \zeta(u, \varepsilon)} f(x+ ru) r^{d-1} \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\mathcal{S}(u), $$ where $u$ is integrated w.r.t. the standard measure over the unit sphere. But notice that as long as $f$ is continuous, $f(x + ru) r^{d-1} - f(x + \delta u)\delta^{d-1} = O(\zeta(u, \varepsilon)) = O(\varepsilon)$ uniformly. Further, the radial integral is over a region of size $O(\varepsilon)$. This means that  $$\int_{u : u_1 \ge \varepsilon/2\delta} \int_{r = \delta}^{r = \delta + \zeta(u, \varepsilon)} f(x+ ru) r^{d-1} \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\mathcal{S}(u) \\ = \int_{u : u_1 \ge \varepsilon/2\delta} \int_{r = \delta}^{r = \delta + \zeta(u, \varepsilon)} f(x + \delta u) \delta^{d-1} \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\mathcal{S}(u) + O(\varepsilon^2) \\
= \int_{u : u_1 \ge \varepsilon/2\delta}  \zeta(u, \varepsilon) f(x+ \delta u ) \delta^{d-1} \mathrm{d}\mathcal{S}(u) + O(\varepsilon^2)\\
= \int_{u : u_1 \ge 0} \zeta(u, \varepsilon) f(x+ \delta u ) \delta^{d-1} \mathrm{d}\mathcal{S}(u) + O(\varepsilon^2),$$ where the final line further uses that if $f$ is bounded, then $\int_{0 \le u \le \varepsilon/2\delta} \zeta(u,\varepsilon) f = O(\varepsilon \zeta(u,\varepsilon)) = O(\varepsilon^2)$. Note that this boundedness of $f$ follows if it is continuous.
Now, note that $\zeta(u, \varepsilon)/\varepsilon \to u_1,$ and is bounded near $0$. So, applying the DCT to switch a limit and integral, we conclude that $$ \lim A(\varepsilon)/\varepsilon = \int_{u : u_1 > 0} u_1 f(x + \delta u) \delta^{d-1} \mathrm{d}\mathcal{S}(u) = \int_{u \in \delta S : u_1 > 0} u_1/\delta \cdot f(x + u) \mathrm{d}\mathcal{S}_\delta(u),$$ using the change of measures $\delta u \mapsto u$ to convert to an integral over the sphere of radius $\delta$.
A similar analysis works for $B(\varepsilon).$ the main change is that we end up getting an integral over $u_1 < 0,$ and the analogue of $\zeta(u,\varepsilon)/u$ converges to $-u_1,$ which gives the required limit for $B(\varepsilon)/\varepsilon,$ and together these lead to the result.

why does it hold? Naturally, this reduces to $$ \int_{B(\varepsilon e_1, \delta) \setminus B(0,\delta)} f(x+v) \mathrm{d}v - \int_{B(0,\delta) \setminus B(\varepsilon e_1, \delta)} f(x+v)\mathrm{d}v =: A(\varepsilon) - B(\varepsilon).$$

This is basically linearity of integration along with the fact that for two sets $U, V, 1_{U} - 1_V = 1_{U \setminus V} - 1_{V \setminus U},$ where $1_{X}$ is an indicator function. Also I'm just defining $A$ and $B$ as the two pieces, in case that was the question.
